# Rotation pitch/yaw reverse problems when picking a tile (2.5D)

Tags: xna, rotation, matrix, isometric

Set-up: 3D world, isometric sprite rendering (4 fixed angles).
This transform matrix is used as camera:

```
 _transform =
            Matrix.CreateRotationZ(Roll) *
            Matrix.CreateRotationX(Pitch) *
            Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(-cameraPosition.X , -cameraPosition.Y, -cameraPosition.Z))* //this matrix controls camera position
            Matrix.CreateScale(new Vector3(_zoomScale)) * //scale representing zoom level. This one applies to the textures too
            Matrix.CreateScale(new Vector3(_textureScale)) * //world scale to fit current texture pixel size.
            Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3((_port.screenWidth / 2) - TileOffset, _port.screenHeight / 2, 0)) //offset for having focus in center of screen instead of top left corner + little offset so it will be a tile center
            ;
```

Roll=-45, Pitch=60. Result:

[image: Iso]

I've hoped to find a quick picking solution in the inverse matrix:

```
_inverseTransform =
           Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(-(_port.screenWidth / 2) + TileOffset, -_port.screenHeight / 2, 0))*
            Matrix.CreateScale(new Vector3(1/_textureScale)) *
            Matrix.CreateScale(new Vector3(1/_zoomScale)) *
            Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(cameraPosition.X, cameraPosition.Y, cameraPosition.Z))*
            Matrix.CreateRotationX(-Pitch)*
            Matrix.CreateRotationZ(-Roll)
            ;
```

It doesn't work as expected.
If i remove rotation from matrix build, everything works. The interesting part is if i leave roll component only, everything works too.
I've tried transposed matrices, inverted matrices, rotating on -angle, FromPitchYawRoll matrix (inverted/transposed/-angles). Every time roll works, pitch and yaw aren't. 
Pitch only/yaw only can't be inverted too.

It's probably something basic in the matrix math/rotation principles, but i'm failing to grasp it. Any help would be appreciated.

--code removed, not relevant to the case--

Some gifs for better understanding.
Current implementation do this:
[image]

If we switch the pitch off, inverse matrix work as intended (white dots mark real tiles grid. Graphical tiles aren't rotated, of course.)
[image]

**EDIT:** 
After some matrix calculations i've realised simple thing. Let's point the mouse on the tile (0,2). If i dump all transformations but pitch by several degrees, then tile (0,2) will be drawed somewhere on (0, 1.25).

[image]

But if i'll apply inverted (or transposed, or "rotate by -value") matrix to the mouse position (0,2), i'll get same (0, 1.25), which means that the mouse is pointing at (0,1) tile. While it should point at (0, 3). And i don't know how to invert this correctly.

I've also discovered [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/31113/how-can-i-improve-my-isometric-tile-picking-algorithm). But, as you can see in the first answer, knight666 is using scale instead of pitch rotation.

Comment: What you're doing seems bug prone.  Why can't you just calculate the inverse of the _transform matrix? It's **a lot** simpler. Matrix.Invert: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.matrix.invert.aspx

Comment: First thing i tried was Matrix.Invert. It didn't work, so i decomposed the thing to find the transformation that caused problems.

Comment: That's the only transformation you're using before your draw calls, there's absolutely no other transforms when putting the verts to the screen at the low level? I'm assuming since you're in 2D you're not using a perspective or view matrix?

Comment: Engine operating in 3D, but for now it's irrelevant. Yes, it's the only transformation, i don't use perspective nor view matrices. 
I've pinpointed the problem (it's somewhat described in the last paragraph of the question). Roughly, the problem is the pitch transform and inverse pitch transform both are shrinking the grid, while for working global inversion invert-pitch component have to expand the grid (as scale transform does)